# Pandas convert from Int64Index to RangeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I concatenated three dataframes. How can I print df.index in RangeIndex, instead of Int64Index?

**My Input**:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
print(df.index)
```

**My Output**:

```
Int64Index([    0,     1,     2,     3,     4,     5,     6,     7,     8,
                9,
            ...
            73809, 73810, 73811, 73812, 73813, 73814, 73815, 73816, 73817,
            73818],
           dtype='int64', length=495673)
```

**Desired Output**:

```
RangeIndex(start=X, stop=X, step=X)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reset_index` to get desired indices. For example:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
df.index

Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

After resetting indices:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.index

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1)
```

Also it is good to use `axis` keyword in `concat` function.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the built-in `ignore_index` option:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3],ignore_index=True)
print(df.index)
```

**From the docs:**

> > ignore_index : boolean, default False
> >     If True, do not use the index values along the concatenation axis. The resulting axis will be labeled 0, …, n - 1. This is useful if you are concatenating objects where the concatenation axis does not have meaningful indexing information. Note the index values on the other axes are still respected in the join.